# SQLite throws "undefined function sqlite_open()" 

Tags: php, sqlite, titanium

I am developing a Desktop application using Titanium in PHP. I am a PHP Web Developer with MySQL DB, new to Desktop with SQLite DB

When I try to open the SQLite DB , it throws a fatal error

the code I used is

```
if ($db = sqlite_open('mysqlitedb', 0666, $sqliteerror)) {
    sqlite_query($db, 'CREATE TABLE foo (bar varchar(10))');
    sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('fnord')");
    $result = sqlite_query($db, 'select bar from foo');
    var_dump(sqlite_fetch_array($result));
} else {
    die($sqliteerror);
}
```

just the example code in PHP.net

PHP.net says that SQLite is bundled with PHP 5+

the error thrown only in TItanium Studio where as

in my XAMPP it all works fine

Could you help?

Comment: undefined function sqlite_open()

Answer (score 2):

The PHP manual page for SQLite's [requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite.requirements.php) says:
`The SQLite extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.0. Beginning with PHP 5.4, the SQLite extension is available only via PECL.`

You may want to check out the version of PHP in use by Titanium Studio.

I've never used this particular IDE before, but this is typically what I do when looking for version and module-related information for PHP:

1. Find the PHP binary (php.exe, php, php5, php-cgi, etc). (Use your O.S. tools to find it)
2. Run `$PHP_BINARY -v` to get the binary's version info.
3. Run `$PHP_BINARY -m` to get a printout of enabled modules for PHP.
4. If sqlite is not listed among the loaded modules, see if it's present in the directory pointed by the `extension_dir` configuration directive (in php.ini).
5. If the module is present as a file, add a line stating `extension = $NAME_OF_SQLITE_FILE` (usually php_sqlite.so or php_sqlite.dll) and see if `sqlite_open()` now works.
6. If the module is not present, see if you can get a pre-compiled binary from the maintainers of the IDE, or if they have specific instructions to build the extension from source.